# Using ForEach with 2 arrays in order to create a new object

Tags: javascript, arrays

So my final result I'm looking for is:

```js
result = [{x: '12/12', y: 90 }, {x: '12/11', y: 0}, {x: '12/10', y: 92}, {x: '12/9', y: 0}, ... ]
```

Now I have 2 arrays. First array is just an array of the last 30 days. I created it using `momentjs` like this:

```js
const lastThirtyDays = [...new Array(31)].map((i, idx) =>
    moment()
      .startOf('day')
      .subtract(idx, 'days')
      .format('MM/D'),
  );
```

which produces:

```js
["12/12", "12/11", "12/10", "12/9", "12/8", "12/7", "12/6", "12/5", "12/4", "12/3", "12/2", "12/1", "11/30", "11/29", "11/28", "11/27", "11/26", "11/25", "11/24", "11/23", "11/22", "11/21", "11/20", "11/19", "11/18", "11/17", "11/16", "11/15", "11/14", "11/13", "11/12"]
```

The next array has a collection of numbers and dates. It looks more like this:

```js
const sampleSet = [
  { date: '2019-12-11', number: 100 },
  { date: '2019-12-10', number: 99 },
  { date: '2019-12-08', number: 101 },
  { date: '2019-12-07', number: 90 },
  { date: '2019-12-05', number: 98 },
  { date: '2019-12-01', number: 96 },
  { date: '2019-11-28', number: 99 },
];
```

So my solution was to use a `forEach` and create an x y dataset. First I tried something like this:

```js
const createDateSet = () => {
  let set = [];
  lastThirtyDays.forEach((date, i) => {
    if (
      sampleSet[i] &&
      sampleSet[i].date &&
      moment(sampleSet[i].date).format('MM/D') === date
    ) {
      set.push({ x: date, y: sampleSet[i].number });
    } else {
      set.push({ x: date, y: 0 });
    }
  });
};
```

That didn't work. Only one of them matched.  So I tried running the forEach on both arrays like this:

```js
const createDataSetBothArrays = () => {
  let set = [];
  lastThirtyDays.forEach((date, i) => {
    let dateItem = sampleSet[i];
    if (dateItem) {
      sampleSet.forEach((datum, i) => {
        if (moment(datum.date).format('MM/D') === date) {
          set.push({ x: date, y: datum.number });
        }
      });
    } else {
      set.push({ x: date, y: 0 });
    }
  });
};
```

But the numbers mismatched.

What would be the proper way to go about this???

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a map and a find to get the corresponding `dateSet.number` :

```js
lastThirtyDays.map(monthAndDay => {
 const date = moment('12/11/2019').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
 const set = sampleSet.find(set => set.date === date);

 return { x: monthAndDay, y: set ? set.number : 0 };
});
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `const date` should reference `monthAndDay`, i.e. `moment(monthAndDay)` instead of `moment('12/11/2019')`. Otherwise you're setting the `number` of every date in the result to the corresponding value of `12-11-2019`.

Comment: @TylerRoper the way you created `lastThirtyDays` is the way to go imo

Answer (score 2):

You could change your `lastThirtyDays` array so that the date format is identical to your `sampleSet`. Not only does this allow you to cross-reference using an exact match, but it's safer in the event that the last thirty days span across multiple years. You can transform it back into your desired display style when constructing the result.

If a matching `date` isn't found, we default `number` to `0` using `|| {number: 0}`.

```js
const sampleSet = [ { date: '2019-12-11', number: 100 }, { date: '2019-12-10', number: 99 }, { date: '2019-12-08', number: 101 }, { date: '2019-12-07', number: 90 }, { date: '2019-12-05', number: 98 }, { date: '2019-12-01', number: 96 }, { date: '2019-11-28', number: 99 }, ];
const lastThirtyDays = [...new Array(31)].map((i, idx) =>
  moment()
    .startOf('day')
    .subtract(idx, 'days')
    .format('YYYY-MM-DD')   // <--- Match format to sampleSet format
);

const result = lastThirtyDays.map(day => ({
  x: moment(day).format('MM/D'), 
  y: (sampleSet.find(({date}) => date === day) || {number: 0}).number 
}));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```